# \$I_i=\sum^n _{j=1} Y_{ij}V_j\$ instead of \$\sum^n_{j=1} Y_{ij} (V_i-V_j)\$.?

Tags: power, current

The equation from the pdf
[image]
[image]

It  said \$I_i=\sum^n _{j=1} Y_{ij}V_j\$,honestly,it confused me for a while,because in my opinion ,the current should be \$(V_1-V_2)Y_{12}\$,so there should be two different voltages,and the \$I_i\$,i think, is the current flows from bus i to every buses ,so why is the current \$I_i=\sum^n _{j=1} Y_{ij}V_j\$ instead of \$\sum^n_{j=1} Y_{ij} (V_i-V_j)\$.?
this confused me for many days,can anyone tell me the reason?

The pdf is here

https://d13mk4zmvuctmz.cloudfront.net/assets/main/study-material/notes/electrical-engineering_engineering_computer-techniques-in-power-system-analysis_load-flow-studies_notes.pdf

Comment: What is equation 5??

Comment: if you click the link,you can know the equation 5 is actually some words,i have edited the question

Comment: I generally don't click links to unknown sites.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we want to write our equation in a very simple matrix form like

$${\bar I} = {\bf Y}{\bar V}$$

where \$\bar I\$ and \$\bar V\$ are vectors and \$\bf Y\$ is a matrix. We define the admittance matrix (\$\bf Y\$) this way so that we can write very "simple" equations to describe our circuit or network while still keeping track of all the details of the circuit behavior.

If we expand this formula out into simultaneous equations, the i'th equation is

$$I_i = Y_{11}V_1 + Y_{12}V_2 + ... + Y_{1n}V_n$$

Your text has just written this in summation notation as

$$I_i = \sum^n _{j=1} Y_{ij}V_j.$$

Trying to write the equation in your form as

$$I_i = \sum^n_{j=1} Y'_{ij} (V_i-V_j)$$

(I've changed the \$Y\$ to \$Y'\$ because the coefficients here would not be the same as in the standard form) would eliminate the possibility of reducing it to a simple matrix equation with only three terms.